# BATCH IF condition for specific format

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, command-line, wildcard

How to form IF condition to be true when 2nd argument are 3 numbers separeted with dot.
I tried this (which should be for any character, not just numbers) but not work.

`IF /I "%2"=="*.*.*" SET VAR=%2`

How can i do that?

Comment: `if` doesn't support placeholders. It searches literally for "star-dot-star-dot-star". Are you numbers between 0 and 9 or can they be 10 or greater?

Comment: Just [0-9] one character, i think this can be done with FOR loop, but i have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "leadnum=123456789"
SET "anynum=%leadnum%0"
FOR %%i IN (
 1.2.3
 123.456.789
 012.345.678
 12.3
 12
 12a.345.678
 12.34.56.78
 12.34.777f
 12.34.
 12.34.56.
 ) DO (
 ECHO %%i|FINDSTR /b /e "[%leadnum%][%anynum%]*\.[%leadnum%][%anynum%]*\.[%leadnum%][%anynum%]*" >NUL
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (ECHO %%i is NOT of format) ELSE (ECHO %%i is IN format)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a demo. You don't say what constitutes a number, so I arbitrarily made the decision to define a number to be a string which starts with a numeric character (except '0') and is followed by any number of numeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

`IF` doesn't support placeholders, so you have to emulate them

```
echo %2||findstr /R "^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$" && (set "var=%2") || (echo no match)
```

`^` start at the first position of the string

`\.` a dot. (`.` only would be "any char")

`[0-9]` any number (you can also use or example [1-9] if needed)

`$` end of string.

`&&` if previous command (findstr) was successful then...

`||` if previous command (findstr) failed then...

Answer (score 0):

```dos
set "value=%2"  & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for %%a in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do set "value=!value:%%a=0!"
endlocal & if "%value%"=="0.0.0" ( set "var=%2" ) else ( set "var=" )

echo(%var%
```

This just replaces all the numbers with a 0 and tests the valid ending value